# Copy price attribute value into newPrice attribute

Tags: attributes, price, product-attribute, products

I have nearly 2000 items, I would like to copy 'price' attribute value to 'newPrice' attribute value for all the items, within table catalog_product_entity_decimal (I think this is the right table)

eg. attribute_id of price is 60, entity_id = 1 and value = 50

```
attribute_id   entity_id   value
60              1           50
60              2           56
```

newPrice - attribute_id = 75

Final Result:

```
attribute_id   entity_id      value
    60              1           50
    60              2           56
    75              1           50
    75              2           56
```

For the subsequent entity_id 1,2,3,4 and so on

SQL query from phpmyadmin? If this is the correct/safe way, what could be mysql query?

any other suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_decimal (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT entity_type_id, 75, store_id, entity_id, value
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE attribute_id = 60;
```